# Self-referencing TypeScript generics in a tree structure

Tags: typescript

We have an abstract tree of elements like this:

```js
abstract class Node<T extends Node<T>> {
    parent: T = null;
    children: T[] = [];
    enabled: boolean;

    findEnabledNodes(): T[] {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return [this];
        }

        const enabledChildren = [];
        this.children.forEach((x) => enabledChildren.push(...x.findEnabledNodes()));
        return enabledChildren;
    }
}

class GenericNode extends Node<GenericNode> {
    name: string;
}

class SpecialNode extends GenericNode {
    description: string;
}
```

This is a greatly simplified version, but for explaining the problem should do.

The idea behind the generics is that calling the method `findEnabledNodes` would return a `GenericNode[]`, which it does. However, for the base case of returning itself if enabled, compiler is complaining that:

```
Error: src/app/classes/node.ts:8:12 - error TS2322: Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'this' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Node<T>'.

8    return [this];
             ~~~~
```

We can use a workaround such as casting it to `unknown` before then re-casting it to `T` like:

```
return [this as unknown as T];
```

But this feels like a pretty dirty approach, and we're not sure if there's a cleaner and safer approach.

Comment: This is a safe cast. The TypeScript type-checker just can't catch the fact that the recursive generic would be the same as the class itself so you're fine.

Comment: Would it suit your use-case to get rid of the generic type and use a polymorphic `this` type? [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgTwHIHsATAUwQG8AoBahAB2CmIDsIAuBCACwEsMAfBEwCuyZAgC8gkcgDcVGrB7JCjJuy68A2gF0JCHXJoJmoZMULsQ+fGeBM9AM2DIwxOfOoPuTQgFEmpuYEJGAAFACU6jxgOuQeRgjcDgihGmAAdCYgZoThcQkFCIwQQlD2mmnahoUAvhTxRrD4TJDGAdnmAMJKKsxRWrqSBg00aemK3Mqq6Q74UL5wnKGhAB554gB8bYGE3ZO9TOm0QmBL6ecrM95+7TnBxGHhT9UFxaX2WTl7U8wvCHV1CgoNAYADizGIUG4sHu+RoAQAtsR2JAoUwAOZ6ADks3wWLkgOB6AQAGVaMRYNxnLDKEYQrAobQINxmijoN5MZIsSAGPiKHUgA)

Comment: @kaya3 if I were to change the return type of `findEnabledNodes` to `this[]`, then the method on the subclass `SpecialNode` would return a `SpecialNode[]`, which is not true - a `SpecialNode` could have `GenericNode` as some of its children.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mL46Vm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.